# How to set the pulseaudio stream name via ALSA?

Tags: alsa, pulseaudio

I am writing an audio application using ALSA (via QAudioInput/Output) that opens two output streams simultaneously. Both ALSA streams use the pulseaudio ALSA plugin. That also works fine and I can assign them to different output devices in `pavucontrol`.

How can I set specific names (and/or other parameters) for those streams such that pulseaudio will remember the stream assignment to specific output devices?

Answer (score 0):

The PulseAudio stream names are hardcoded as "ALSA Playback" in the plugin.

To use another then PA's default output device, you would have to [create your own ALSA devices](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-plugins.git;a=blob;f=doc/README-pulse;hb=HEAD).

Comment: You mean, adding more "pulse" devices to `~/.asoundrc`? Or writing a separate ALSA plugin?

Comment: Adding more devices based on the pulse plugin, as described in the README I linked to.